# Course scheduling

Tags: scheduling, planning

I'm looking for a tool for scheduling courses based on the following constraints :

- There are 3 group of students : A,B and C. They take some courses together, but they also have specific courses to their program.
- Groups A and B are not available at certain predefined slots, so I have to accommodate everything else around that.
- Those groups must be together for the lectures, but they have to be split into two lab groups. So, group C can have a lab session when group A is not available due to the first hard constraints.
- Therefore, each time slot can have from 1 to 3 groups in parallel.

I looked at optaplanner but it seems it does not support my requirements.

I use Mac OS, Windows and Linux. For the price, I don't have a predefined budget. If it seems interesting, and I can propose to buy it or a subscription.

Thank you so much.